# How to use std.prune() with a function?

Tags: jsonnet

I have a function that takes one required parameter and two optional parameters.  I want the function to prune out the optional parameters from the result if they are not provided, but it evaluates to an empty expression.

My function:

```
local newTaskParam(pName, pDesc=null, pDef=null) = {
    local param = std.prune(
        {
            name: pName,
            description: pDesc,
            default: pDef,
        },
    )
};
{
    test: newTaskParam("pipeline-debug"),
}
```

Current Output:

```
{
   "test": { }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
   "test": {
      "name": "pipeline-debug"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are returning an empty object with:

```
local func() = {
  // expected here to return field: value pairs
};
```

For your purpose, the easiest way should be returning the result of calling std.prune() *without* "building" the returned object yourself:

```
local func() = std.prune(
);
```

Thus, you could implement it as:

```
local newTaskParam(pName, pDesc=null, pDef=null) = std.prune(
  {
    name: pName,
    description: pDesc,
    default: pDef,
  }
);
{
  test: newTaskParam('pipeline-debug'),
}
```